# How to extract the data from this javascript variable into a string

Tags: javascript

Google chrome tells me that the javascript variable is this:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

And each Object is of this form:

```
option: "Text I need 1"
__proto__: Object
```

I think this may be called a double array but I could be wrong. For me to obtain my goal I need to have a javascript variable like this:

```
myresult = "Text I need, Text I need 2, etc"
```

Basically, I want the option text from all the objects in the second line above and separated by a comma.

Answer (score 5):

More or less:

```
var i, s = "", f = [o1, o2, o3];
for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    s += f[i].option;
    if (i != f.length-1) s += ", ";
}
```

*Edit* As Pointy's comment suggests, just using the `.join(', ')` method would be better than the ugly manual version above.

```
var i, a = [], f = [o1, o2, o3];
for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++) { a.push(f[i].option); }
var s = a.join(', ');
```